# Mostrar notificaciones push en app android

Tags: firebase, notificaciones, cloud, fcm

Deseo saber si es posible almacenar y mostrar en la pantalla principal de una app las notificaciones push enviadas por Firebase Cloud Messaging

Comment: Mira por favor [ask]. Intentaste algo? investigaste algo al respecto?

Comment: Si es posible, lo manejas como un `servicio` y comunicas ese servicio con tu pantalla principal `activity` a través de un `broadcast` . Para almacenarlo en local hay muchas formas, te recomiendo que uses room. Eso es a grandes rasgos, se necesita mas información para ayudarte